# Assign variable in Parent Environment of a function

Tags: r

Look at example below, I have assigned variable holder to the global environment. However, I want to assign holder exclusively to the local environment of make.var(). How do I do so?

```
make.var<-function(){
  holder<<-rep(NA,10) #assigns global
}

test<-function(){
  make.var()
}
```

EDIT: I think the term that is frequently used "calling environment" as opposed to "parent environment".

Comment: You could check out `?assign` -- possibly in "pos = parent.frame()". Why don't you, simply, make `make.var` to return a value that you can assign wherever you need?

Comment: @alexis_laz I will take a look at it. I basically have to assign (initiate) a lot of  variables. I think if I returned a list of these variables it would be troublesome.  It would be easier if they were all assigned in the parent environment in a one-liner.

Comment: Return a list and use list2env()

Answer (score 8):

You can get a calling environment using `parent.frame` (don't confuse it with `parent.env`) and assign variables to it using `$` or `[[` (as you do with lists). 
Or you can use `assign`.

E.g.

```
rm(list = ls())
`%<-1%` <- function(x, y) { p <- parent.frame() ; p[[deparse(substitute(x))]] <- y }
`%<-2%` <- function(x, y) { assign(deparse(substitute(x)), y, env = parent.frame())}
```

And then:

```
ls()
a1 %<-1% 111
ls()
a2 %<-2% 222
ls()
a1 ; a2
test1 <- function(x) { print(ls()); t %<-1% x; print(ls()); t }
test2 <- function(x) { print(ls()); t %<-2% x; print(ls()); t }
ls()
test1(333)
ls()
test2(444)
ls()
```

Comment: FYI, If you need to go back multiple generations, e.g. you have an if statement inside an apply function, inside the main function that has the variable you want to update, you can specify the argument `n` for parent.frame().